# Convert XML to JSON with pebble.js

Tags: javascript, xml, json, cloudpebble, pebble-js

I am writing a small application for my Pebble. The intent is to send web services to a server and then process the XML response. The problem here is that Pebble.JS does not support XML responses, only text or JSON responses. I am looking for a way to convert the response to JSON to easily make use of the information. I cannot find a working way for Pebble.JS to accomplish this.

Does anyone know how to get the attributes and the child elements (with its attributes) of the XML in JSON in Pebble.JS?

Thanks!

Comment: What makes you think that "Javascript natively don't support XML"? Here's a good place to start on XML parsing: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Parsing_and_serializing_XML

Comment: @IMSoP Javascript itselfe supports XML, but I am not able to find any working solution for pebble.js, so I think it is not supported by pebble.js.

Comment: I fixed your post. Pebble.JS uses jQuery Mobile. This means it only processes responses as Text or JSON, no XML response support (though the `XMLresponse` function works, but will only provide you raw text as a string)

Comment: Hey, did you manage to fix this issue in the end? I ask because I have not found any solutions yet.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Node XML Parser like this one (https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js) and make it compatible to a "browser" with Browserify (https://github.com/substack/node-browserify).

Browserify usage: 
browserify raw-app.js -o compiled-app.js

I think you need to have nodejs installed too but this isn´t a big problem.

Here some code which written on-the-fly:

```
   var xml2js = require('xml2js');

   var xml = "<root>This is a root object!<child>This a child</child></root>"

   xml2js.parseString(xml, function (error, result) {
       console.log(result); // JSObject
   });
```

Comment: This would work but adds a lot to the project in terms of filesize that may otherwise be used for the app. Remember that a Pebble app is limited to 100kB in size.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that jQuery Mobile does not support responses coming in as XML. I have quite annoyingly run into this issue before. The way I got around it was by creating my own JSON Object with the expected response tags in the following way:

```
var IDs = message.match(/<id>(.*?)<\/id>/g);
var tempID = IDs[0].replace('<id>','').replace('</id>','');
```

That's just a part from my actual project that I was working on this for. It will require a little bit of modifying as per your needs to get it to how you want it. You likely will want to have that second line inside a loop with some other arrays from your `.match()` calls, when making your JSON Object. At the end, you need to use the `JSON.parse(...);` function call to assign a variable the JSON addressable object you've made.